# Error creating database with doctrine orm symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

When I try to create a database with the command

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I get those errors

```
2019-04-02T12:45:01+02:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:d
atabase:create". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [104
5] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for u
  ser 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: YES)
```

I uninstalled xmapp, composer, symbony and installed them again.

- PHP version 7.3.3
- Composer version 1.8.4
- Symfony CLI version v4.3.3

Followed those steps to install orm doctrine found here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

```
 composer require symfony/orm-pack
 composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle
```

Modified *.env* file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123456@127.0.0.1:3306/test
```

Then, executing

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

And then, the error comes.

Comment: that seems you have a problem with the user credentials .

Comment: did you fill the doctrine section parameters in config.yml ?

Comment: It must be due to `doctrine/dbal` related problem then. Try downgrading its version to 2.4 as this issue says.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16150

Answer (score 1):

The `.env` file was looking like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123456@127.0.0.1:3306/articles
```

I just removed the password, and the problem was solved:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/articles
```

Now the database is created.

Answer (score -2):

Verify once whether doctrine package is installed or not ?

```
$ composer require doctrine/doctrine-bundle
```

Then, enable the bundle by adding the following line in the app/AppKernel.php file of your project:

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...

        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    );

    // ...
}

// ...
}
```

Comment: It is installed, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? Why do you think that the bundle should not be installed? If it was not installed, the OP should have seen an error message telling him that the command was not available

Comment: Probably it should have been the same way you have mentioned, I am not pretty much sure, but in my case while setting up the project I missed to add this bundle resulting in similar error. After adding the above solution it got fixed and working fine.